# How to check a customer object is null or not in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

In `java` it is easy to check an object is null or not.

How to do the same in `flutter`?

`Java` code

```
class Student { 
     String name; 
     int age; 

     Student(String name, int age){
           this.name = name;
           this.age = age;
     }
}
```

Consider above class has getter and setters.

Object creation and null check

```
Student student1 = new Student("Andrew",21);
Student student2 = new Student();
if(student2 != null){ 
     System.out.println(student2.getName());
}
```

Dart Code

```
class Student {
     String name;
     num age;
     
     Student(this.name, this.age);
}
```

Object creation and null check

```
Student student1 = new Student("Andrew",21);
Student student2 = new Student();

if(student2 != null){ // How to check this object is null or not?
     // statements
}
```

How to check `student2` object is null or not in dart?

Comment: If you're using null-safety (which is enabled by default in Dart 2.12 and later), then `student1` and `student2` *cannot* be `null`.  I strongly recommend reading https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety.  If you instead declared `student1` and `student2` with nullable types (i.e., as `Student?`), then you could check if they're `null` exactly as you've done.

Comment: FWIW: I removed the Java tag, as the question is really about Dart. Those who know Java, but not Dart (like me!) aren't in a position to help.

Comment: `if(student2 != null){ ` works perfectly fine. What are you having problems with?

Comment: @jamesdlin I'm missing something. If I declare `Student? student1 = new Student("Andrew",21);
Student student2? = new Student();` , then `if(student2 != null){` gives me the following message in DartPad `The operand can't be null, so the condition is always true.`  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @GrahamD If `student1` and `student2` in that example are *local* variables, the Dart compiler can easily deduce from control flow that they can never be `null`, even though you declared them with nullable types.

Comment: @jamesdlin The OP's question was how to detect if student2 is null or not. My point is that with the variable being instantiated as `Student student2 = new Student();` or `Student? student2 = new Student();` It can be never be null. It is at best  an empty Student object. The second part of your initial comment refers and is what has confused me as it does not appear correct.

Comment: @GrahamD Yes,my previous comment was not quite accurate.   I did not realize it was being used in the context of a local variable with no intermediate code between the declaration and the check.

Comment: Ok, cool. Thought I was losing it.

Answer (score 0):

In Dart, 'everything is an object', including 'null' - the Null class.

If you declared the following variable `Student? student2;` then `student2` would be null.

Because you declared it as `Student student2 = new Student();` it is no longer null, it would have been created as an empty object of type Student. I say 'would have' because null safety will not let you do that since your two class variables (name and age) are defined as non-nullable. In order for you to create (construct) an empty Student object your class would need to be

```
class Student {
     String? name;
     num? age;
     
     Student(this.name, this. Age);
}
```

Having created an empty Student object this way, you cannot test it for null. You need to check `student2.name == null` `student.age == null` or any suitable combination thereof. You could also define an isEmpty method in the Student class that checked for both those variables being null `bool isEmpty() => (name == null && age == null);`.

Then

```
if (student2.isEmpty()) {
  print("2 is empty");
}
```

prints that 2 is empty.

Hope that helps.